# Usage of single quotes in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, apostrophe

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id_zam AS test, 
     CASE WHEN (SELECT something FROM sth WHERE id_something = test) = 1 
          THEN 
              'true' 
          ELSE 
              'false'  
     END as test_result
FROM testTable
```

`something` equals 1. So the CASE statement is TRUE so it's going to execute `THEN` statement which is `'true'`

But when I add single quotes around the alias `test` like this:

```
SELECT id_zam AS 'test', 
     CASE WHEN (SELECT something FROM sth WHERE id_something = 'test') = 1 
          THEN 
              'true' 
          ELSE 
              'false'  
     END as test_result
FROM testTable
```

The query returns `'false'`. Can anyone explain why they're different?

Comment: 'test' is a string, test - column name.

Comment: Single quotes should be used only to define string and date constants.  Without quotes, `test` refers to a columns; with quotes `'test'` is the string "test".

Comment: It appears that you are confusing apostrophes with back ticks (to the left of the `1` on the keyboard).  Back ticks are used in mysql to denote a column name, apostrophes are used to denote a string.

Comment: The OP never used back ticks in the question though, so I don't think there's confusion there. I think OP's real question is why `'test'` isn't treated like an alias, which is because adding single quotes causes it to be treated like a string, not an alias.

Comment: Yeah, now I know the difference. And thank you for realizing me the difference between a single quote and backticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single quotes (or apostrophes, if you prefer) are used to represent strings (sometimes dates) but not integer values.

I assume your `id_something` is an integer variable. If that is the case, the problem lies in that you are trying to compare an integer to a string, which will always return false.

In the first example, you selected an integer and gave it the alias `test`. When you do your comparison, you're comparing two integers which is valid. However, once you change it to `'test'` you now have a string, which is in no way related to the `id_zam`. When you do your comparison of an integer and a string, it returns false by default.

**EDIT**
This is true for aliases, but not necessarily true all the time. In this example yes, `test` is an alias and `'test'` is a string literal, so they will be treated differently. However, by MySQL defaults, single quotes won't affect the comparison of other items. For example, if you had a query with condition `1 = '1'` this will return true. See the comments to this answer for another explanation.

To reemphasize, and simplify, don't use single quotations if you want to compare something using an alias.

Comment: Unless you've got strict modes enabled, mysql won't care about `'42'` v.s. `42`. It'll convert as appropriate.

Comment: *"...you are trying to compare an integer to a string, which will always return false."* Not necessarily. In a default installation, `1 = '1'` will always return true.

Comment: That won't hold true for an alias though, will it? I can edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're not notified by default, @MarcB.

Comment: yes, but aliases are essentially field names. `'foo'` is a string literal, `foo` is a field/table/alias. They're totally different things and can't be auto-converted the way mysql would for an integer 42 v.s. string 42.

Comment: @MarcB okay, I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' and Marc, great catch. Didn't even cross my mind in this example.

Answer (score -1):

You get false because this subquery:

```
SELECT something FROM sth WHERE id_something = 'test'
```

does not return a single record equal to 1.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I edited my question. I meant `something` equals 1

Comment: That's not necessarily why it's false. The reason it's not returning a record is because the comparison is incorrect, which is the difference between OP's two examples.